# using InputContext.selectInputMethod to specify a keyboard layout always fails

Tags: java, keyboard, internationalization

I am writing an English/Arabic dictionary in java. I want the app to automatically set the keyboard to the appropriate layout depending on the search language. I save the keyboard Locale information like this:

```
    JTextField tf = (JTextField) e.getSource();
    InputContext ic = tf.getInputContext();
    Pref.setInputLocale (Pref.getSearchIndex(), ic.getLocale().toString());
```

And restore it like this:

```
    JTextField tf = Ui.makeTextField (20, "", searchListener);
    controlPanel.add(tf);
    String ls = Pref.getInputLocale(Pref.getSearchIndex());
    if (ls.length() > 0) {
        Locale l = new Locale (ls);
        InputContext ic = tf.getInputContext();
        System.out.println (ic.toString());
        System.out.println (l.toString());
        System.out.println (ic.selectInputMethod (l));
    }
```

The system output for three successive switches of the input language looks like this:

```
sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext@38e3c8d0
en_us
false
sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext@38e3c8d0
ar_eg
false
sun.awt.im.InputMethodContext@38e3c8d0
en_us
false
```

The system output shows that the locale strings are being saved and restored successfully, however the InputContext.selectInputMethod always returns false, and the keyboard is not switched to arabic. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because ic.getLocale.toString()  produces "en_us" but Locale () wants "en","US".

The solution is to replace this code

```
        Locale l = new Locale (ls);
```

with this code:

```
        ls = ls.replace("_", "-");
        Locale l =  new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag(ls).build();
```

This first turns the underscore into a minus, then uses setLanguageTag which
tolerates lowercase letters for the country.